# Converting my HTML from one form to another

Tags: html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am just going through some poor HTML markup on my old web-pages. I've noticed a few mistakes to my markup which are recurring.

I was hoping to fix these with a program but am not sure what API or language would help me accomplish this.

My HTML is of this form :

```
<td class="bulletPoint" align="right" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%">This is text</td>
```

which I want to replace with

```
<td class="bulletPoint" align="right" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%"><h2>This is text</h2></td>
```

I also have this kind of form (class/colspan/href can vary) :

```
<td class='original' colspan=4><a id='id12345' class='content' href='#note'">This is the text</a>
```

And want to convert it to this :

```
<font SIZE="3"  COLOR="#222222"  FACE="Verdana"  STYLE="background-color:#ffffff;font-weight: bold;"><h2>This is the text</h2></font>
```

What's the best way to programmatically do this when I have over 1,000 .html files to perform this operation on?

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated; you should not be using it in new code.

Comment: Surely it's easier to create 1 css file of properties and just remove the inline html properties from all the files?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with the second line, but this should work for the 1st substitution as long as the <td>...</td> is on one line `cat file.html | sed 's;\(<td class="bulletPoint" .*>\)\(.*[~<]\)\(.*\);\1<h2>\2/h2><\3;g'`

Comment: Use regex replace all. The feature is in most IDEs and a lot of text editors. You would need to do 2 seperate replaces for the different outputs you want though, just make sure the regex is specific enough to only match the ones you want

Comment: you are missing a </td> in your 3rd line, and I guess you are trying to wrap all the "This is the text" with your 4th line. Is it so? (Deprecated <font> issue appart)

Comment: if it is one time activity, you can use any editor and just find and replace all. However, if it is continous process , then you can spend time in coding based on your expertize area, like i am java guy so will use HTMLDocument api from java swing.

Comment: Depending on the quantity of changes to make, I would go like @Panther with the editor Find and replace solution. In my own case, I would go with Notepad++ and use the Find in Files + replace function, heavily relying on Regexes. May require some testing, but should get you all the way.

Comment: font tag is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“What is the best way to programatically” do it, depends on which tools you know best. I would do it with python and beautifulsoup. Other people may vouch for sed and regex. See my approach:

Create two separate directories, one with a **"copy"** of your original .html files and another where your modified files will go (not a subdirectory of the original ones).

Run the following python3 program in one run or separate runs according to what you have. You are not altering the original files, and you can always erase the modified ones and try again.

You can alter the selections of class_, colspan, href, etc... as you see fit, as well as create several programs, one for every case you may run into.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

do = dir_with_original_files = '/path/to/your_original_files'
dm = dir_with_modified_files = '/path/to/your_modified_files'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(do):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('~'): #you don't want to process backups
            continue
        original_file = os.path.join(root, f)
        mf = f.split('.')
        mf = ''.join(mf[:-1])+'_mod.'+mf[-1] # you can keep the same name 
                                             # if you omit the last two lines.
                                             # They are in separate directories
                                             # anyway. In that case, mf = f
        modified_file = os.path.join(dm, mf)
        with open(original_file, 'r') as orig_f, \
             open(modified_file, 'w') as modi_f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())
            for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='bulletPoint'):
                t.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2'))
            # The following loop could belong to a separate python progam
            # which would follow the same general structure.
            for t in soup.find_all('td', class_='original'):
                font = soup.new_tag('font')
                font['size'] = '3'
                font['color'] = '#222222'
                font['face'] = 'Verdana'
                font['style'] = 'background-color:#ffffff;font-weight: bold;'
                t.string.wrap(soup.new_tag('h2')).wrap(font)
            # This is where you create your new modified file.
            modi_f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(<([^ ]+)[^<>]+>)([^<]+?)(<\/\2>)
```

Try this.Replace by `\1<h2>\3</h2>\4`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vF0kU2/6

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(<([^ ]+)[^<>]+>)([^<]+?)(<\/\2>)')
test_str = u"<td class=\"bulletPoint\" align=\"right\" valign=\"top\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\">This is text</td>\n<td class='original' colspan=4><a id='id12345' class='content' href='#note'\">This is the text</a> "
subst = u"\1<h2>\3</h2>\4"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to change your files.

I've done this a couple of times. I am not sure how familiar you are with .NET and C#. Here is little pseudo-code to get you started:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlFromFile);

IList<HtmlNode> tableDataCells = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").Where(x =>x.Attributes["class"] == "bulletPoint").ToList();
foreach (HtmlNode td in tableDataCells)
{
    // add code to insert h2 tag into data cell
}
```

I hope this helps.